# SvelteKit - "ReferenceError: File is not defined"

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, svelte, sveltekit

A quick problem I faced while developing a web-app using SvelteKit (and by extension, Vite):

Inside the `<script>` tag of my `+page.svelte` file I tried defining an empty placeholder `File` object the following way:

```
    let formObject: FormCreationData = {
        fileToUpload: new File([], ''),
        anotherField: "",
        ...
    };
```

While it should work in normal JS/TS (and Svelte if you aren't using SvelteKit), **it now throws the following error**:

```
ReferenceError: File is not defined
    at +page.svelte:13:14
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

Since SvelteKit implements Server-Side Rendering (SSR) - The code that is on the `+page.svelte` file **has to run both on client browsers and the Vite server**.

The `File` class is only available in browsers, so it won't be able to fulfill this requirement (You might know that Node.js offers the `fs` module in order to allow for file operations instead).

This means that there are two ways to possibly fix this problem:

1. **Disable SSR** using the variable `ssr` in the `+page.ts/js` file:

   ```
   export const ssr = false;
   ```
2. Find a way to define the `File` object at a point where the code runs on the browser (This can be done by checking the `browser` variable under the `$app/environment` module, or inside of one of the supported Svelte hooks, such as `onMount()`).